# Is it possible to add a two dot in a variable name in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want to create a variable like this in javascript

```
variable1.varible2.variable3 = "Hi Its working";
alert(variable1.varible2.variable3);
```

Comment: I don't know whether or not this is even possible, but even if it is, why would you _want_ to do this?  This could lead to seriously unreadable code, since `variable1.something` can now mean multiple things.

Comment: I need to add the third also

Comment: this is what i actually want my previous code
var mockwindow = {};
            mockwindow.location = "https://www.replacedurl.com/document";
            alert(mockwindow.location);

I want to add the third like alert(mockwindow.location.href)

Comment: I agree with Tim. This is where you usually have an object with another object exposed. For example you could have a car object with an engine object with a type as property. Then you could write   
Car.engine.type = "V8 Turbo"

Comment: @AlbertoL.Bonfiglio example please

Comment: @lovefrp You will need to create an object and implement a [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) (or similar) method.

Comment: that's not a variable, it's setting an object property. That is, if you already have an object called `variable1`, which has a property `variable2` that holds another object, then you can set a property called `variable3` on it with that code. But it doesn't, and can't, assign to a new variable. The `.` character is not legal in a JS identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have `.` in variable names.

> You can call a variable pretty much anything you like, but there are limitations. Generally, you should stick to just using Latin characters (0-9, a-z, A-Z) and the underscore character.

If you really want the `variable1.varible2.variable3` to return value `"Hi Its working"`. You can use objects.

```js
let variable1 = {
  variable2:{
    variable3:"Soemthing"
  }
}
console.log(variable1.variable2.variable3)
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant use `.` for the name of a variable but you can do this with objects:

```
let person = {
  name: {
    first: 'john',
    last: 'snow'
  },
  eyes: {
    color: 'black'
  }
}
console.log(person.name.first); //john
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var car = new Object();
car.type = "Fiat";
car.model = "500";
car.color = "white";
car.engine = {type:"V8", fuel:"diesel"}
console.log(car)

window.alert(car.engine.type)
```

Then you could write Car.engine.type = "V8 Turbo"